# Octave sample code failing to compile in g++?

Tags: c++, octave

I'm attempting to get the Octave C++ code [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html) to compile in `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-1ubuntu1~12.04) 4.6.4)`.

This trimmed version of the above will compile in `g++`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//  Matrix L=Matrix(2,2);

  return 0;
}
```

but if I unremark out the line `Matrix L=Matrix(2,2);` then compile with `g++ temp.cpp` it gives the error message:

```
/tmp/ccTa3Am5.o: In function `Array2<double>::~Array2()':
temp.cpp:(.text._ZN6Array2IdED2Ev[_ZN6Array2IdED5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `Array<double>::~Array()'
/tmp/ccTa3Am5.o: In function `Array<double>::Array(dim_vector const&)':
temp.cpp:(.text._ZN5ArrayIdEC2ERK10dim_vector[_ZN5ArrayIdEC5ERK10dim_vector]+0x26): undefined reference to `Array<double>::get_size(dim_vector const&)'
/tmp/ccTa3Am5.o:(.rodata._ZTV5ArrayIdE[vtable for Array<double>]+0x10): undefined reference to `Array<double>::~Array()'
/tmp/ccTa3Am5.o:(.rodata._ZTV5ArrayIdE[vtable for Array<double>]+0x18): undefined reference to `Array<double>::~Array()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm unsure why.  Perhaps I'm missing an `#include`, perhaps I don't have an appropriate file installed, perhaps I'm not linking to the appropriate library, or perhaps I'm misusing Octave in some way.

> **Question**:  Why is this failing to compile?  How can I fix it?

It compiles fine if I use `mkoctfile --link-stand-alone temp.cpp` as indicated at the above site, however, I'd like to use `g++` if possible, since I eventually want to be able to call Octave functions from another program I've written in C++.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Howto Use Octave Functions in C/C++ Programs](http://www.mathias-michel.de/download/howto-octave-c%2B%2B.ps), which provides some useful information about how to compile C/C++ code with octave included. On Page 2 you will find an example of how to compile such a program using g++

Comment: It's not failing to compile, all of those are linker errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in my comment a simple example can be found [in this Howto](http://www.mathias-michel.de/download/howto-octave-c%2B%2B.ps). So in your case a simple way to achieve compilation will be creating a makefile as follows:

```
makefile:
all: temp

clean:
    -rm temp.o temp

temp: temp.o
      mkoctfile --link-stand-alone -o temp temp.o

temp.o: temp.cpp
        g++ -c -I$(OCTAVE_INCLUDE)
        -I$(OCTAVE_INCLUDE)octave -o temp.o temp.cpp
```

`$(OCTAVE_INCLUDE)` is an environment variable that should be set to your octave include path (e.g. `/usr/include/octave-x.x.xx`). Then you can simply compile and link your test application using the command `make all`.

Comment: This works for me (but we need tabs in the Makefile, instead of spaces, before commands).

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to the octave library. If the library is `octave.a`:

```
g++ -loctave temp.cpp
```

Comment: Not that easy - you should let the `mkoctfile` do the linking for you when working with Octave in C/C++. Can save you a lot of headaches ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add the library directories to your link command:

- your-local-path\octave-x.x.xx\lib\
- your-local-path\octave-x.x.xx\lib\octave\x.x.xx\

`mkoctfile -L"\your-path\octave-x.x.xx\lib" -L"\your-path\octave-x.x.x\lib\octave\x.x.xx" --link-stand-alone temp.cpp`

For cxx11 linker errors:
[Converting std::__cxx11::string to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring)

"If you get linker errors about undefined references to symbols that involve types in the std::__cxx11 namespace or the tag [abi:cxx11] then it probably indicates that you are trying to link together object files that were compiled with different values for the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro. This commonly happens when linking to a third-party library that was compiled with an older version of GCC."

Defining the following macro before including any standard library headers should fix your problem:

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
```